# Random Custom Font rendering issue with react-native IOS Webview

Tags: ios, webview, react-native, font-face, wkwebview

I tried every trick on the book I know. But When I jump to quickly from one webview to another the custom font get lost and does not render anymore.

I have a font inside the native code and a @font-face fallback on the css part:

Logging from XCode:

```
Nea: (
    "Nea-Bold",
    "Nea-Regular"
)
```

From the css file:

```
$PLANET-FONT-FAMILY-BLACK: "Nea-Bold", "Nea Bold", "neaboldwebfont", "Avenir LT Std 85 Heavy", "Arial";
$PLANET-FONT-FAMILY-BOOK: "Nea-Regular", "Nea Regular", "nearegularwebfont", "Avenir LT Std 85 Roman", "Arial";

/* Fonts */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nea Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-bold-webfont.svg#neabold") format("svg"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-bold-webfont.eot") format("opentype"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nea Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-regular-webfont.svg#nearegular") format("svg"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-regular-webfont.eot") format("opentype"),
  url("../../../../../assets/fonts/nea/nea-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```

It works most of the time unless, I reload the webview too fast. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Ah no never figured it out :(